# C# Extremely Slow to Load Hard-coded static Data

Tags: c#, performance, jit, .net-4.8

OK - This is a very strange one.  We have an app that needs a bunch of static data that doesn't change very often so I thought instead of taking a hit on a database read or file read, I would simply embed the entirety of the static data, like so:

```
public class MyData {
  private static List<MyType> Data { get; set; }
  public static void LoadStaticData() {
    Data = new List<MyType> {
      new List<SubItem> { ... }, Other, Fields, Here
      , new List<SubItem> { ... }, Other, Fields, Here
      , new List<SubItem> { ... }, Other, Fields, Here
      .. etc 
    }
  }
}
```

My thought was that since it's simply loading the contents into memory as fast as possible it should be remarkably fast in all cases.  However, in reality, when this app is loaded for the first time, the simple act of loading a list as above (with ~270 total items) is taking 2-3 seconds!  When I profile it with VS or dotTrace it basically just shows that this takes 2-3 seconds with absolutely nothing else going on.

Further when I try to test this in LINQPad with the same code, I notice that the first time I run it, it takes 2-3 seconds.  But the second time it takes <1ms, which is what I would have expected.  I suspect there is something going on with JIT in this code here, but it completely defeats the purpose of fast loading of static data.  How do I accomplish embedding ready-to-go static data into my app, without needing any IO or avoiding the JIT performance hit?

**Update**

Per request, here is a project to repro: https://github.com/mellamokb/perf-77632383/.  First run to generate the total list takes ~330 ms on my machine, then the second run takes ~1ms. I forgot there are a lot of subtypes so it is a little misleading when I say 270 types - there are also thousands of subtype records as well.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without being able to reproduce it ourselves. It seems *likely* that there's some type initialization or JITting going on, but we can't really tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair. Took a bit since it's proprietary code and I wanted something of similar scale and volume.  This should repro: https://github.com/mellamokb/perf-77632383/.  When I test, the first load takes ~330ms, the second load 1ms.

Comment: As you know, off-site code is subject to link rot.  Any way to trim it down to a MRE you can post here?

Comment: @DaveS: First, it's my own private GitHub repro so should be around awhile :). Secondly the nature of the issue is that it takes 10K+ LOC to demonstrate the issue, which is hardly possible to embed in a SO question.  If you glance at the attached repro the concept is very simple, it just takes a large-ish size static list to really show the issue.

Comment: @mellamokb: I've just made a tweak in the code so that the first time each of the list properties is hit, it returns a very short list instead... this doesn't affect the timing at all, which basically supports the theory that this really is JIT compilation. It's hard to know whether for your production code, the JIT compilation that's taking time is for the types themselves, or the collection initialization.

Comment: What kind of app is it? Is it interactive? Over the years (particularly in the days of much slower everything), I've found that doing slow initialization on a secondary thread (with a simple interlock to prevent access before initialization) can go a long way to speed up _apparent_ slowness

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, JIT really does seem to be the issue.  Ironically we intentionally embedded the data to improve performance only to make it 100x worse... guess an embedded static file is really the way to go!  Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @Flydog57 It is background process with simple UI (progress bar), but called from an MSAccess UI via COM hundreds of times per day.  I suspect it will only have cold start performance hit on first run of the day, and stay loaded but we notice the performance every time we run it in development.  The actual process it is running is really short (5-10 seconds).

Comment: Generally a giant hard-coded initialization is a bad idea due to JIT, like you've found. Best to embed a resource file with some JSON or XML or something.